# Including CSS and JS files in Yii Framework

Tags: javascript, css, include

I met a problem while trying to include CSS and JS files by registerScriptFile and registerCssFile method in Yii Framework.

I gathered all CSS and JS files which put in head tag,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery.ad-gallery.js"></script>   
<link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/css/jquery.ad-gallery.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

moved them into header widget and replaced with these code:

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/css/jquery.ad-gallery.css');
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/js/jquery.ad-gallery.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

CSS files turned out without any problem. However, JS files seemed to fail and encounter error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'**

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The "jquery.ad-gallery.js" file may be connected to the page before jquery. Try removing the option "POS_HEAD" or replace it with "POS_END".

Comment: Make sure that defining variable "home_url" is earlier than connection script file which use it.

Comment: It works when I remove the option POS_HEAD. But another error encounter:
Uncaught ReferenceError: home_url is not defined 

In web head tag, I defined a JS var home_url:

 <script type="text/javascript">    
        var home_url =  '<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)."/" ?>' ;
    </script>

Comment: Please help me with "defining variable "home_url" earlier than connection script".

Comment: Where are you using this variable? Can you show pice of code?

Comment: Here is the code. I put them in head tag
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <script type="text/javascript">    
        var home_url =  '<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)."/" ?>' ;
    </script>

 
</head>

Comment: Here you are defined it. But where you use this variable?

Comment: I use this variable to define url in file lib.js, which was also included in head tag. Here is the code contain this variable:

var url_root = home_url;
var uploaded_files_location = home_url+"images/tempimage/"+directory+"/Albumplace/originimage";

Comment: You need to enclose this code in `$(function(){ ... })` or add file lib.js after determining this variable: `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/js/lib.js', CClientScript::POS_END)`

Comment: I've try both of your suggestion. But this var still not define.

Comment: Try to define these variables as follows: 
`window.url_root = home_url; 
window.uploaded_files_location = home_url+"images/tempimage/"+directory+"/Albumplace/originimage"`
Maybe their determination is performed inside the function and therefore they are not defined in the global space.

Comment: It turns out as a syntax error when I try your method:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: Yes, my last comment - nonsense! You need to look at the code of the page and make sure that the file "lib.js" connects to the page after the definition of this variable. Also try execute `home_url` in browser console and see the value of this variable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally find out the error. Yii method seem to put the JS and CSS link behind title tag. So I try putting this var right above title tag. And it's done.